# Create a numpy array of mixed column types from data using genfromtxt

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

My question is how to create a numpy (np) array from a csv file which has columns of type int, and string. I found np.genfromtxt to be documented as the function of choice for this [1,2]. I am using python 3.5.1 and numpy 1.11.0. However, the latest numpy documentation I found is for 1.10.0 [3]. As I get an numpy error further down, this might be of interest.

Let me start with what I have

```
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

# Define the input
input = "1,3,Hello\n2,4,World"

# Create a structured np.array from input by reading from BytesIO.
output = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(input.encode()),
                       delimiter=',',
                       dtype=None)

# output.dtype.names -> ('f0', 'f1', 'f2')
```

Here, the columns f0 and f1 are of type int, and f2 is a byte array. Thus

```
output['f2'] == 'Hello'  # -> False
```

is false, as the type differs. A proper comparison must be written as

```
output['f2'] == b'Hello' # -> [True, False]
```

I would prefere to compare to a string and not a byte array. Thus, I want f2 to be of type str. The solutions should be to state the types of each column explicitley. According to [1], this should be possible by setting the genfromtxt argument

```
dtype=(int, int, str)
```

such that the minimal example now reads

```
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

# Define the input
input = "1,3,Hello\n2,4,World"

# Create a structured np.array from input by reading from BytesIO.
output = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(input.encode()),
                       delimiter=',',
                       dtype=(int, int, str))
```

However, this results in a `TypeError: data type not understood`. Maybe, something has changed between numpy version 1.10.0 and 1.11.0. In any case, I can not get this to work.

Therefore, I tried a second approach using the converters argument of genfromtxt. With this argument, values can be transformed by a function. The example now reads

```
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

# Define the input
input = "1,3,Hello\n2,4,World"

# Create a structured np.array from input by reading from BytesIO.
output = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(input.encode()),
                       delimiter=',',
                       dtype=None,
                       converters={2: lambda x: str(x, encoding='utf-8')})
```

By doing so, f2 is in deed of type `<U`, which I interpret as utf-8 in little-endian encoding, but only an empty string `''` is present is each row of f2.

So, how can I read in the given data such that f0 and f1 are int and f2 is str?

[1] http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html

[2] http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

[3] http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/

Comment: Is this related to `TeX` at all?

Comment: no, you should ask it at stackoverflow

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry. I used the wrong login.

Comment: In `py3` your test input could be simply `txt=b'1,2,....'.splitlines()`, a list of bytestrings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dtype` code for Unicode strings is `U`. For work with fixed-sized blocks, the length is needed. In this case `U5` is sufficient:

```python
>>> np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(input.encode()),
                      delimiter=',',
                      dtype=(int, int, 'U5'))
array([(1, 3, 'Hello'), (2, 4, 'World')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<U5')])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I set the block size too wide, say U20, the type fo the respective columns is <U20, but the actual content has its correct length. Thus, is a say U5 string stored in a U20 block, such that space for 15 characters is "wasted"?

Comment: @ReedWood Yes, the type must have a fixed size. Each row has a fixed size called stride, it can be accessed by the array attribute `stride`. If you want to inspect the underlying byte data, then the attribute `data` can be used as in `bytearray(a.data)` with `a` as array object. `a.nbytes` gives the byte size. The above array, but with `U20` uses 192 bytes for the two rows. The stride is 96 bytes, 8 byte for each integer and 80 bytes for the unicode string, which uses 4 bytes per character.

Comment: The length of the Unicode string is implicit. For the string representation, the trailing code points with zero as numeric value are ignored. Embedded characters with code zero are fine as long as there is a non-zero character at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Makes sense to me.